# Change HTML5 video src does not work in Safari mobile browser

Tags: html5-video, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have a scenario, i have to play two video in HTML5 player in mobile browsers. The videos are playing fine in desktop browsers. 
one thing i know , 
We not autoplay videos in mobile browsers, user has to tap on the video player to play video.

What i am doing, on video ended event of first video i am changing the src of the . but sometimes it is shaky or it does not plays the second video. user has to tap on play button to play 2nd video. I just need to exclude the 2nd tap. YouTube is doing this somehow. The ad video plays fine, the player minimize and then the 2nd video starts playing.

It takes much time to play the video on start.

Following is my sample implementation. try this url in iPhone or Android
http://abuzer.github.io/videojs-liverail-vpaid/sample.html

```js
 <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    video1 = 'https://d3hh3bpy3h68fd.cloudfront.net/processed_videos/47fad7e0-7477-0132-8e95-123139254ded/_preview_640x480_2932_edit.mp4';
    video2 = 'https://drgta5lwz3cck.cloudfront.net/uploads-public-videos/fd6eefe0-73cc-0132-a03a-12313b07582a/640x480.mp4';
    video1Played = false;
    video2Played = false;

    $(function() {

        $('#playAd').on('click', function() {
            $('#playAd').hide();
            $('#videoElement').attr('src', video1);
            $('#videoSource').attr('src', video1);
            $('#videoElement')[0].play();
            video1Played = true;
        });


        $('#videoElement').bind('ended', function() {
            if (video1Played && !video2Played) {

                $('#videoElement').attr('src', video2);
                $('#videoSource').attr('src', video2);

                $('#videoElement')[0].load();
                $('#videoElement')[0].play();
                video2Played = true;
            }
        });
        $('.videoElement').bind('progress', function(e) {
            $('#state').hide();
        });

        $('.videoElement').bind('waiting', function(e) {
            $('#state').show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>


    <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>

  <!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
 
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="playAd">Click to Play</button>


    <div id="videoWrapper" style="">
     <div id="state" style="display:none; text-align: center">
         <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://www.loadinfo.net/images/preview/14_cyrle_four_24.gif?1384388177">
     </div>
        <video  x-webkit-airplay="allow" id="videoElement" class="video-js videoElement vjs-default-skin" height="50%" width="100%" controls src="" poster="">
            <source id="videoSource" src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <!--   <video data-setup="{}" x-webkit-airplay="allow" id="videoElement1" class="video-js videoElement1 vjs-default-skin" height="50%" width="100%" controls src="" poster="">
            <source id="videoSource" src="https://d3hh3bpy3h68fd.cloudfront.net/processed_videos/47fad7e0-7477-0132-8e95-123139254ded/_preview_640x480_2932_edit.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
   -->
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```